# How to change a value in a column dependent on a grepl in R

Tags: r, if-statement, extract, grepl

I would like to change the values in one column depending on what I match in a grepl from another column in my data.frame.

Example of Data.frame:

```
df
SHOT    CLASS     DATA_TEXT
shot1   missed     missed Jumper
shot2   made       made Three Point Jumper
shot3   made       made Jumper
```

what I have been trying:

```
df$SHOT_TYPE <- as.vector(0) #create new variable

for (i in 1:length(df)) {
if(grepl("e Jumper", df$DATA_TEXT[i]))  { df$SHOT_TYPE <- "Jumper" 
} else if(grepl("d Jumper", df$DATA_TEXT[i]))  { df$SHOT_TYPE <- "Jumper" 
} else if(grepl("t Jumper", df$DATA_TEXT[i]))  { df$SHOT_TYPE <- "Three" } }
```

Doing this method each `if statement` just overwrites the last.

My current results:

```
df
SHOT    CLASS    DATA_TEXT                 SHOT_TYPE
shot1   missed   missed Jumper             Three
shot2   made     made Three Point Jumper   Three
shot3   made     made Jumper               Three
```

What I would like the results to look like:

```
df
SHOT    CLASS    DATA_TEXT                 SHOT_TYPE
shot1   missed   missed Jumper             Jumper
shot2   made     made Three Point Jumper   Jumper
shot3   made     made Jumper               Three
```

Any help will be appreciated. Please let me know if any further information is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
df$SHOT_TYPE <- ifelse(grepl('d Jumper|t Jumper', df$DATA_TEXT), 'Jumper',
                       ifelse(grepl('e Jumper', df$DATA_TEXT), 'Three', NA))
```

Produces output:

```
   SHOT  CLASS               DATA_TEXT SHOT_TYPE
1 shot1 missed           missed Jumper    Jumper
2 shot2   made made Three Point Jumper    Jumper
3 shot3   made            made Jumper      Three
```

NOTE: I coded as NA the columns that don't match the three patterns. You can modify the code to suit what you need.

Comment: Thank you for your Answer. If I take out the "or" and do two separate `ifelse` then it works great. If I leave the "or" in then it shows the shots that should be `Jumper` as `NA`.

Comment: Are you sure you are reading the data frame with stringsAsFactors = FALSE? Not sure. It works for me. Even then, you can nest another `ifelse()` to get your desired result with the 'or' in `grepl`.